# Text missing from top of page: margins?

Tags: pdftex, page-breaking, margins

When building and viewing `LaTeX > PDF` on `TeXnic Centre`, I am having run-over paragraphs missing the first line of text.

(by run-over I mean paragraphs that move onto a new page due to a pagebreak - automatic or manual, without change of chapter)

For instance, see below

[image: missing text]

How can I go about specifying that there should be white space at the top of such pages?

Edit: packages, etc. are

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}


%% Language %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-font for non-english texts and characters

%% Packages for Graphics & Figures %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx} %%For loading graphic files
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could do `\usepackage[margin = .5in]{geometry}`.  This will give you half inch margins all around.  Or you could set the top margin alone if you want to keep the 1in  left and right margins.  `[top = .5in]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a MWE, I could only speculate, but in order for me to re-create the top being cut off, I had to set the top margin to a negative value in the article class.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = (desired length)in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

---

With the option `[top = -.5in], the output was

[image]

---

Set to `0in` it wasn't cut off

[image]

---

Finally set to `.5in`, the output was

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. It had to be explicitly stated. What's more - it was my fault; back from when there was no section that was greater than one page (and I wanted to remove some of the excessive whitespace)

%\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.875in}

Comment: @Duncan I am glad it all worked out for you.